# How can I find the last member of an array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How can I find the last member of an array in PostgreSQL?
for example you have an array of the numbers which each of them are id of a course, in the list of your chosen courses I want to know the last one : [1,32,4,6] I need number 6 ! how can I find the last number which is 6 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array function `array_upper()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) to get the index of the last element.

Consider:

```
with t as (select '{1,32,4,6}'::int[] a)
select a[array_upper(a, 1)] last_element from t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=05623077e30d91d134c2905001b4e07a)**:

```
| last_element |
| -----------: |
|            6 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ARRAY_UPPER` to get the upper bound of your array. You can then retrieve the value at that returned index.

```
SELECT yourcolumn[ARRAY_UPPER(yourcolumn,1)] FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: You can just open another question.

Comment: Please open a new question.